# Травмопункт и травмпункт

Tags: грамотная-речь, словоизменение, языковые-изменения

Сейчас в словаре оба этих слова, но до какого-то времени я не слышал, чтобы произносили без О или писали. Действительно раньше был только *травмопункт,* а *травмпункт* сравнительно недавно появился?

Comment: Артём, а у меня наоборот. *Травмопункт* – может, и слышал, но не видел. В городе большими буквами везде было "ТРАВМПУНКТ".

Comment: Интересно. А в каком городе?

Comment: В НКРЯ 18 документов с О (первое 1989 годом) и 34 без О (первое 1988 годом). В Кемерове

Comment: Спасибо за статистику, Александр!

Comment: В старых книгах можно встретить "эвакпункт", но в современных словарях только *эвакопункт*. Тенденция, однако.

Comment: Интересно очень, grizzly, спасибо!

Comment: @grizzly «Эвакопункт» — эвакуационный пункт. Эвакопункт — это сложное слово образованное от основ двух слов «эвакуация» и «пункт», которые соединены соединительной гласной «о», а «травмпункт» — это сложносокращённое слово от «травматологический пункт», а не сложное.  В каких старых словарях вы нашли «эвакпункт»?

Comment: @grizzly В «травматологии», в отличии от «эвакуации»  два корня -травм- и -лог-. Если это сложное слово, как «эвакопункт», куда делся тогда второй корень?

Comment: _— А теперь, гражданка, я вас сведу в **эвакпункт**, недалеко. Там примут, поживете сколько надо. Спросили бы на вокзале, вас сразу и направили бы куда следует_ (М. Шагинян. Кик).  [https://nemaloknig.net/read-234268/?page=9]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Кто и какие словари считает  авторитетными?**

Ну, это всё от наблюдателя зависит: кто смотрит и какие словари видит.
Лучше всего посмотреть самому и заглянуть сюда:

ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКИЙ АКАДЕМИЧЕСКИЙ РЕСУРС «АКАДЕМОС»
http://orfo.ruslang.ru
Там можно увидеть два варианта:  **травмопу́нкт**  и **травмпу́нкт.**

И уж конечно лучше не слушать чужие авторитетные мнения, если нет уверенности в том, что они действительно  авторитетные.

Цитата: *Если речь идёт о Большом толковом словаре с Грамота.ру, то это не авторитетный источник.*

2. **Вопрос № 265004**

Вопрос: как правильно звучит сокращение от "травматологический пункт" -
травмопункт, травмапункт или травмпункт.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка.** Это сокращенное слово есть в электронных словарях нашего портала: травмопункт, -а и травмпункт, -а

3. **А это еще одно интересное мнение с другого форума**

Правильно «травматологический пункт», остальное лишь сокращение! Кому как удобнее, тот так и выговаривает! Вот работал в моей клинике один стоматолог, так он говорил "бломба".  Я ему тактично намекаю: мол, Лёша, как тебе не стыдно при пациентах говорить не "пломба",  а "бломба",  на что он преспокойно и вразумительно отвечает: «А мне так удобней!».  Потом я этого Лёшу уволил, уж очень он был.... не ахти! Но это совсем другая история!

А в документах (справках или выписках) вы нигде не встретите ни первое, ни второе, а будет написано: «Выдано травматологическим пунктом…"  И никак иначе! Скажу по долгу службы (челюстно-лицевой хирург, понимающий в логопедии), что некоторым просто неудобно произносить звуки ВМП,  им куда проще выговорить ВМОП,  вот и вся премудрость! Если что, можете всех недовольных и сомневающихся посылать ко мне, я им уздечку языка или верхней губы подрежу и будут как миленькие всё выговаривать:))

4. Вот, оказывается, в чем дело – в этом слове **неудобное стечение согласных**. Почему неудобных?

В – смычной губно-зубный звук, М – сонорный губно-губный звук,  П – смычной губно-губный звук. **Представляете, какая здесь должна быть артикуляция!** Поэтому и стали писать гласную О, чтобы произношение было более удобным.  И не народная этимология здесь виновата – объяснить ситуацию можно  вполне научной фонетикой. В самом деле, не уздечку же всем подрезать!

Оба варианта **вписываются в словообразовательную** систему языка, поэтому их стали считать равноправными. Каждое слово индивидуально, и не стоит все слова строить в ряд,  "стричь под одну гребенку" и оформлять **по единому образцу** – у каждого своя история.

Примечание. Интересное это выражение – "**народная этимология**", кто и когда применил его первым? Может быть, по аналогии можно говорить о "народной грамматике" или "народной лексикологии"? Будут представители этих направлений учить нас, **как выбирать** авторитетные словари и определять **единственно возможный способ** образования слова.

Comment: К ответу добавлю еще следующее. Если нам неудобно произносить какие-то сочетания согласных, то мы начинаем их упрощать.  И тогда будем произносить: тра (МВ)пункт. Вот и получится "трамва"   вместо  "травмы", потом на орфографии скажется. Думаю, этот факт тоже учитывался,  когда нормировалась форма "травмопункт", сейчас в словаре она стоит даже на первом месте.

Comment: *«Лучше всего посмотреть самому и заглянуть сюда»* Почему именно сюда лучше всего?

Comment: Потому что  Электронный «Орфографический академический ресурс АКАДЕМОС» Института русского языка им. В.В. Виноградова РАН является официальной публикацией. Словарь ежегодно обновляется. Кроме того, две формы были зафиксированы уже в издании 1999 года, это не новшество.  Поэтому вашу минусовку уже принятого ответа, соответствующего  академическим словарям, я считаю незаконной.

Comment: @Sharon По вашей ссылке: *«В АКАДЕМОС исправлены ошибки, обнаруженные со времени выхода словаря (напр., амипалон → аминалон), изменено написание ряда слов (напр., особоохраняемый → особо охраняемый), сняты отдельные слова-фантомы (напр., лентный, фармкарта). При исправленных и измененных словах дается соответствующее указание [опечатка в РОС 2012: амипалон], [изменено, ср. РОС 2012: особоохраняемый]»*. Это говорит о том, что в этом словаре могут быть ошибки, как и в любом другом, потому что его составляли люди, которые, как и любые люди, могут ошибаться.

Comment: @Sharon *«Кроме того, две формы были зафиксированы уже в издании 1999 года, это не новшество»*. Словарь АКАДЕМОС основан на Русском орфографическом словаре 2012 года и, следовательно, его не существовало в 1999 году.

Comment: @Eagle, опечатки одно, ошибки другое. Это ещё не даёт оснований признавать словарь не авторитетным. Словари на Грамоте самые официальные на сегодняшний день.

Comment: @Серж Мне непонятно значение слова «официальный» в «официальные словари». **Официльный — исходящий от правительства или администрации, диктуемый их законами, правилами.** *Официальное делопроизводство, распоряжение. Официальное опровержение. Официальное лицо (должностное). О. язык государства (используемый в законодательстве, судопроизводстве, делопроизводстве)* [Ожегов].  Вы о чём?

Comment: @Серж В моём ответе: *«внесение некоторых форм слов в словарь оценивается как спорное, так, например, слово „жéвачка“, зафиксированное в словаре как разговорная форма, может являться отражением произношения, а не новым словом (производным от глагола „жевать“)».* Это опечатка? Может «травмопункт» тоже является отражением разговорного произношения, а не новым словом? Словарь составляет человек, и я не рассматриваю составителя данного словаря, как заслуживающего доверия. Вы рассматриваете, это ваше дело. Почему это вас так задевает? Я дал свой ответ, дайте свой, если не нравится мой – тут свобода

Comment: При чем тут новое не новое? Словари составляют лингвисты. В данном случае сотрудники института русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

> Сейчас в словаре оба этих слова...

В каком именно словаре?

Я вижу в словарях только «травмпункт».

Если речь идёт о Большом толковом словаре с Грамота.ру, то это не авторитетный источник:

> Внесение некоторых форм слов в словарь оценивается как спорное, так, например, слово «жéвачка», зафиксированное в словаре как разговорная форма, может являться отражением произношения, а не новым словом (производным от глагола «жевать»). Иначе, по предположению критика, фиксации произносительных вариантов, в словарь следовало бы включать и такие несуществующие слова как «черезвычайно» и «психиатор», поскольку такое произношение слов «чрезвычайно» и «психиатр» является достаточно распространённым. Также подвергается сомнению необходимость фиксации словарём таких разговорных вариантов произнесения слова, как, например, «договорá», что, по мнению того же критика, продиктовано желанием составителей увеличить объём словаря. Высказанные замечания не отменяют ряд важных достоинств словаря, которые позволяют рассматривать его как уникальный справочник по русскому языку. [[wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0)]

Соединительная гласная используется при соединении основ слов в сложном слове:

> При соединении основ двух и более слов в одно сложное слово, а также при образовании сложных слов с составными частями интернационального характера используется соединительный гласный, передаваемый на письме буквами *о* и *е.* [[orfogrammka.ru](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/)]

> Соединительные гласные – это соединительные морфемы для образования **сложных слов**: мореплаватель, лесозаготовки. [[resh.edu.ru](https://resh.edu.ru/subject/lesson/6961/conspect/258679/)]

«Травмпункт» — это не соединение основ от «травма» и «пункт», а сокращение от «травматологический пункт». Посмотрите на [фотографию](http://cdn01.ru/files/users/images/df/c5/dfc52964c4d318a614b01091d9079d18.jpg) выложенную пользователем [[поль­зоват­ель забло­киров­ан]](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/profile44747/) при обсуждении этого вопроса на [bolshoyvopros.ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1321723-kak-pravilno-travmpunkt-ili-travmopunkt.html)

«Травмпункт» — это не сложное слово, а сложносокращенное.

> В русском языке есть особый способ образования слов, характерный только для существительных: в образовании нового слова участвуют не полные, а сокращённые части основ слов. Такие слова называются сложносокращёнными, или аббревиатурами (от латинского «сокращённый»). Сложное слово, состоящее из сокращённых основ слова, называется сложносокращённым. Например, слово завуч образовано из сокращённых частей слов заведующий учебной частью. Слово универмаг образовано от сокращённых частей слов универсальный магазин. [[resh.edu.ru](https://resh.edu.ru/subject/lesson/6961/conspect/258679/)]

Заметьте: не «универомаг», а «универмаг» — универсальный магазин.

Пользователь [[Корне­тОбол­енски­й]](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/profile554215/) сайта [bolshoyvopros.ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1321723-kak-pravilno-travmpunkt-ili-travmopunkt.html) приводит другие примеры слов с частью «-пункт» в конце:

> Насколько я помню, также пишутся и многие другие сокращённые слова с
> заключительной частью "пункт": *ветпункт, корпункт, медпункт,
> агитпункт, продпункт, заготпункт, здравпункт*.

Скорей всего, ошибочное слово «травмопункт» возникло из-за [народной этимологии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F) объясняющей его как соединение основ слов «травма» и «пункт», и, таком образом, нуждающегося в соединительной гласной «о».

Comment: Спасибо! Ещё пришла в голову "горбольница". Но есть одно но: в первом корне на конце две согласных, а в ваших примерах по одной (всего две).

Comment: В *спортплощадке*, например, тоже две. Скорее всего, О в *травмопункте* появляется из-за того, что В и М звонкие, их труднее произнести без гласной перед следующей согласной.

Comment: Точно, поэтому) В спортплощадке даже четыре всего, отличный пример!

Comment: @Артём Луговой Я не совсем понял аргумент насчёт согласных.  Я об этом вообще не говорил. Вы считаете, что на сложносокращённые слова должны распространяться правила для сложных слов по вставке соединительных гласных? Но ведь у них другой способ образования. О каком перовом корне вы говорите? Если образовать сложное слово от «травматологический пункт», оно бы содержало три корня, как «электрокофемолка». В «травматологический» два корня  -травм- и -лог-. Если это сложное слово, куда делся тогда второй корень? При таком образовании сложного слова была бы не «электрокофемолка», а «электрокофе».

Comment: @Артём Луговой В «завуч» вообще три слова сокращено: заведующий учебной частью. В «заведующий» корень -завед- или -вед-, но точно не «за», которое от «заведующий» осталось. От «учебной» и «частью» вообще осталось по одной букве. Разве имеет смысл говорить о корнях в сложносокращённых словах и о том, как они должны соединятся между собой? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я просто искал похожие примеры, а так согласен с Sharon. От заведующего осталось всё-таки *зав,* не *за.*

Comment: @Артём Луговой Да, осталось «зав», но сути вопроса это не меняет. В чём вы согласны с Sharon? Она пишет: «Если нам неудобно произносить какие-то сочетания согласных, то мы начинаем их упрощать. И тогда будем произносить: тра (МВ)пункт». Т. е. «травмОпункт» было изначально и упростилось до траВМпункт? Она пишет: «Вот и получится „трамва“ вместо „травмы“». Это как? Никакой «травмы» вообще не было, была «травматология». Она пишет: «Думаю, этот факт тоже учитывался, когда формировалась форма „травмопункт“». Нет такой формы.

Comment: Не важно, травма или травмотология. Я думаю, она и не возражает, что от последней это. Sharon имела в виду, насколько я понял, что МВ здесь некоторым легче выговорить, чем ВМ, поэтому иногда происходит такое превращение. Такое же, например, в ошибочном "тубаретка".